# Crawling on uncerficated website

Tags: python, scrapy

I am both new to Python and Scrapy, but I am trying to get some data from a website that has an untrusted certificate, and I think this is why I can't crawl it, although maybe I just did the spider wrongly

Here is the error log I get when I try to crawl

```
2013-10-24 21:19:08-0200 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.18.4 started (bot: tutorial)
2013-10-24 21:19:08-0200 [scrapy] DEBUG: Optional features available: ssl, http11, libxml2
2013-10-24 21:19:08-0200 [scrapy] DEBUG: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'tutorial.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['tutorial.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'tutorial'}
2013-10-24 21:19:12-0200 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2013-10-24 21:19:15-0200 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2013-10-24 21:19:15-0200 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2013-10-24 21:19:15-0200 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines: 
2013-10-24 21:19:15-0200 [tutorial] INFO: Spider opened
2013-10-24 21:19:15-0200 [tutorial] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2013-10-24 21:19:15-0200 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6023
2013-10-24 21:19:15-0200 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2013-10-24 21:19:16-0200 [tutorial] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://matriculaweb.unb.br/matriculaweb/graduacao/oferta_campus.aspx> from <GET http://matriculaweb.unb.br/matriculaweb/graduacao/oferta_campus.aspx>
2013-10-24 21:19:16-0200 [tutorial] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://matriculaweb.unb.br/matriculaweb/graduacao/oferta_campus.aspx> (failed 1 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'OpenSSL.SSL.Error'>>]
2013-10-24 21:19:17-0200 [tutorial] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://matriculaweb.unb.br/matriculaweb/graduacao/oferta_campus.aspx> (failed 2 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'OpenSSL.SSL.Error'>>]
2013-10-24 21:19:17-0200 [tutorial] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET https://matriculaweb.unb.br/matriculaweb/graduacao/oferta_campus.aspx> (failed 3 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'OpenSSL.SSL.Error'>>]
2013-10-24 21:19:17-0200 [tutorial] ERROR: Error downloading <GET https://matriculaweb.unb.br/matriculaweb/graduacao/oferta_campus.aspx>: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'OpenSSL.SSL.Error'>>]
2013-10-24 21:19:17-0200 [tutorial] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2013-10-24 21:19:17-0200 [tutorial] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/exception_count': 3,
     'downloader/exception_type_count/scrapy.xlib.tx._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived': 3,
     'downloader/request_bytes': 1064,
     'downloader/request_count': 4,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 4,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 384,
     'downloader/response_count': 1,
     'downloader/response_status_count/301': 1,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 24, 23, 19, 17, 283862),
     'log_count/DEBUG': 10,
     'log_count/ERROR': 1,
     'log_count/INFO': 3,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 4,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 4,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 4,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 4,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 10, 24, 23, 19, 15, 955787)}
2013-10-24 21:19:17-0200 [tutorial] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

And here is my code

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.item import Item

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'tutorial'
    allowed_domains = ['matriculaweb.unb.br']
    start_urls = ['http://matriculaweb.unb.br/matriculaweb/graduacao/oferta_campus.aspx']

    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/oferta_dis.aspx?cod=\d+'))),Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/oferta_dados.aspx?cod=\d+&dep=\d+')), 'parse_dep')]

    def parse_dep(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        discplina = Disciplina()

        url_disciplina = '/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr/td/table[4]/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/center/table/tbody/tr/td/font/strong/a'.re(r'.*cod=([0-9]+)')
        yield Request(url_disciplina, meta={'disc':disciplina}, callback=self.parse_disc)


    def parse_disc(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        disciplina = response.request.meta['disc']

        disciplina['nome'] = sel.xpath('/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr/td/center/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]').extract()
        disciplina['codigo'] = sel.xpath('/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr/td/center/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]').extract()
        disciplina['requisitos'] = sel.xpath('/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr/td/center/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]').extract()

        yield disciplina
```

If someone could help me I would be incredibly grateful

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**UPDATE**: This workaround is for Scrapy<1.1. Newer version have a setting to change the tls method, see http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.1/topics/settings.html?highlight=context#downloader-client-tls-method

My answer from the scrapy-users list:

Sometimes the openssl's negotiation metho don't get along with the server. There are three available methods: TLSv1, SSLv2 and SSLv3 (or SSLv23).

When the ssl handshake fails for some reason you can discard if it's directly related to the negotiation method using curl:

```
 $ curl --tlsv1 -k https://matriculaweb.unb.br/matriculaweb/graduacao/oferta_campus.aspx

 $ curl --sslv2 -k https://matriculaweb.unb.br/matriculaweb/graduacao/oferta_campus.aspx

 $ curl --sslv3 -k https://matriculaweb.unb.br/matriculaweb/graduacao/oferta_campus.aspx
```

Scrapy uses TLSv1 by default. See https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/core/downloader/contextfactory.py#L13

A workaround is to provide your own client context factory and set the negotiation method that works with the website. For example:

```
# file: myproject/contextfactory.py
from OpenSSL import SSL
from scrapy.core.downloader.contextfactory import ScrapyClientContextFactory


class MyClientContextFactory(ScrapyClientContextFactory):
    def __init__(self):
        self.method = SSL.SSLv23_METHOD  # or SSL.SSLv3_METHOD
```

And set the setting:

```
DOWNLOADER_CLIENTCONTEXTFACTORY = 'myproject.contextfactory.MyClientContextFactory'
```

You can test that this work by simply running:

```
$ scrapy shell https://matriculaweb.unb.br/matriculaweb/graduacao/oferta_campus.aspx
```

Comment: 2016-06-20 15:27:54 [py.warnings] WARNING: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py:50: UserWarning: 
 'acknowledgements.contextfactory.MyClientContextFactory' does not accept `method` argument (type OpenSSL.SSL method, e.g. OpenSSL.SSL.SSLv23_METHOD). Please upgrade your context factory class to handle it or ignore it.
  warnings.warn(msg)

Comment: @DaniilMashkin for scrapy>=1.1 use this setting instead http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.1/topics/settings.html?highlight=context#downloader-client-tls-method